# How do you change the Silverlight loading screen's background?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I'm trying to avoid the default Silverlight loading screen displaying before my applet and was trying to show a blank coloured background, the same colour as my applet's.  The aim is to avoid the jarring white and make it look like it's all part of one app drawing.

I've discovered [SplashScreenSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838219%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) but I'm not sure how to hook that up to just show a single colour background instead of the loading screen.  Any suggestions?

Comment: I've actually managed to use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838130(v=vs.95).aspx to display an image sometimes, but it seems that by the time the fake loading screen has loaded so has my applet.  So is there any way to avoid the white screen altogether?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add new XAML file to ASP.NET website, in which Silverlight will be shown.
Replace content of XAML with this:

```
<Grid xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
<StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center">
<Grid>
<Rectangle x:Name="progressBarBackground" Fill="White" Stroke="Black"
StrokeThickness="1" Height="30" Width="200"></Rectangle>
<Rectangle x:Name="progressBar" Fill="Yellow" Height="28" Width="0">
</Rectangle>
</Grid>
<TextBlock x:Name="progressText" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
Text="0% downloaded ..."></TextBlock>
</StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Next, you need to add a JavaScript function to your HTML entry page or ASP.NET.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function onSourceDownloadProgressChanged(sender, eventArgs)
{
sender.findName("progressText").Text =
Math.round((eventArgs.progress * 100)) + "% downloaded ...";
sender.findName("progressBar").Width =
eventArgs.progress * sender.findName("progressBarBackground").Width;
}
</script>
```

To use this splash screen, you need to add the splashscreensource parameter to
identify your XAML splash screen and the onsourcedownloadprogresschanged parameter to
hook up your JavaScript event handler. If you want to react when the download is finished, you
can hook up a different JavaScript event handler using the onsourcedownloadcomplete
parameter:

```
<object data="data:application/x-silverlight," type="application/x-silverlight-2"
width="100%" height="100%">
<param name="source" value="ClientBin/SplashScreen.xap"/>
<param name="onerror" value="onSilverlightError" />
<param name="background" value="white" />
<param name="splashscreensource" value="SplashScreen.xaml" />
<param name="onsourcedownloadprogresschanged"
value="onSourceDownloadProgressChanged" />
...
</object>
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: I'm not using an ASP.NET website, but could the XAML just live in a separate file and have the same effect?

Comment: I think yes, it must be in separate file, and other parts must be places in page where your silverlight application is located(may be html file or other)