# Silverlight performance testing

Tags: wpf, silverlight, performance-testing

Can anybody recommend me a tool or an approach to measure the performance of silverlight object inside of Internet Explorer object?

An approximate test scenario is

*Start Timer; Open the page, Wait until the silverlight object raise an event (for ex. OnDisplayed()); Stop Timer;*

OR

*Start Timer; Open the page, Wait until the silverlight object will be displayed completely; Stop Timer;*

Can I do this from C# program? Or it is easier to do this with some tool?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can change loading page for your silverlight application and start timer when loading started. When loading finished you can stop timer and show result.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3836443/how-do-you-change-the-silverlight-loading-screens-background/3836908#3836908) is code for changing loading page.

Comment: Is it possible to connect to Silverlight object and create the event handler for it?

Comment: As I know you can access html elements from silverlight. In that case you can keep time of start loading. Than when your event fires you can take time and compare it with time for loading. Hope this will help you.

Comment: I have no access to the code, We have a tool to test, there is an internet explorer object inside of the tool, which contains a silverlight object :) I'm not sure if it is possible to modify the code on the fly. May be it is possible to connect to the silverlight object and then create an event handler for the event I need?