# Busy Indicater or what?

Tags: silverlight, busyindicator

In any silver-light business application  project before silver-light project file (.xap file) loaded to the browser a busy indicator (or whatever it called) is displayed with loaded percent and blue balls rotating around in circle.
my guess it should be some where in the testpage.Aspx but not sure where..!

So here is my questions
 1: Where it comes from ?
 2: Can i change it ? If yes then how..??
[Find Image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4OUr.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate, see this question: ["How do you change the Silverlight loading screen's background?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3836443/how-do-you-change-the-silverlight-loading-screens-background).

Comment: @icebat  Hey thanks.. Ur link helped me to go in right path.. other wise i never know that screen is Splash Screen and not busy indicator.. Thanks once again..

Comment: @ Andrew Barber has deleted My answer..?? Don't know why ?

Comment: I think beacause it wasn\`t actually an answer (more details in [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)). And the question seems to be duplicate anyway. But I think you got your answer, right? It\`s what actually matters, isn\`t it? =)

Comment: i got the answer thanks to ur link.....